# django tables2 create extra column with links

Tags: django, hyperlink, django-tables2

I am trying to add a extra column to one of my tables, that adds url to another page.

My Table:

```
class ItemTable(tables.Table):
    edit = tables.LinkColumn('item_edit', args=[A('pk')])
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('name', 'slot', 'klass', 'rarity', 'price')
```

my urls:

```
url(r'^admin/item/edit/(?P<item_id>\d+)/$', views.item_edit, name='item_edit')
```

Now with this, i get my table, but the last column (edit) only has dashes + the page crashes when i click the title.

i have been looking at http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#django_tables2.columns.LinkColumn  and im not sure where i go wrong

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problems you've encountered are caused by `LinkColumn` expecting to be bound to a specific attribute in your `Item` model, i.e. it is looking for an `Item.edit` attribute on your instances.

Since you don't actually have an `Item.edit` attribute, ordering over your `edit` column makes no sense, and you should mark it as *non-orderable*:

```
from django_tables2.utils import A
edit = tables.LinkColumn('item_edit', args=[A('pk')], orderable=False)
```

The text of the link itself would come from the value of the `Item.edit` attribute, which you don't have, so you will need to provide it yourself by adding a `render_edit` method to your table class:

```
def render_edit(self):
    return 'Edit'
```

You can replace the `'Edit'` string with whatever you want displayed in that column.

Update: As suggested by @SunnySydeUp, you also need to specify `empty_values=()` for the column, in order to get its value rendered:

```
edit = tables.LinkColumn('item_edit', args=[A('pk')], orderable=False, empty_values=())
```

References:
http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/order-by-accessors.html#specifying-alternative-ordering-for-a-column
http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/custom-rendering.html#table-render-foo-methods

Disclaimer: This answer is based on the `django-tables2` documentation and source code, and hasn't been tested on an actual Django application.

Comment: Thanks for this clear explanation, this indeed solves the problem about the ordering problem. However all my "links"  are still just an unclickable "—" any idea where this is going wrong?

Comment: You also need to add `empty_values=()` to the column. Look at the 2nd reference.

Comment: Yes the values now show, except its not a link yet just a string

Comment: Can you post your current table class definition, with all discussed changes applied?

Comment: The reason it's just a string and not a link is because you have overidden the render method for the edit column to just return a string. You should probably return a string with an anchor tag, eg. "<a href='url'>Edit</a>, but it'll probably be easier just to use a `TemplateColumn`.

Answer (score 6):

To have the link properly formatted and with a link text of your choice, you can do the following in the table class:

```
def render_edit_link(self,record):
    return mark_safe('<a href='+reverse("edit", args=[record.pk])+'>Edit</a>')
```

Where 'edit' is the name of the url.

Comment: Also need to mention that LinkColumn text argument needs to be set.

Answer (score 3):

I create clickable links in extra columns with

```
edit = tables.LinkColumn('item_edit', text='Edit', args=[A('pk')], \
                         orderable=False, empty_values=())
```

It's not necessary to override the render method; the 'text' parameter changes the text of the link from 'none' to 'Edit', for example.