# Django tables 2 add link column to edit model

Tags: python, django, web, django-tables2

I'm using django-tables2 for a project. I want to create a new column which links to the admin page of that model so it can be edited. Can I do that?

Comment: Does this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22941424/django-tables2-create-extra-column-with-links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. The admin views have a [fix naming scheme](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls). The change view url of a specific instance can be reversed from `'admin:appname_modelname_change'` and takes the instance's primary key as an argument:

```
from django_tables2.utils import A

column_name = tables.LinkColumn(
  viewname = 'admin:applabel_modelname_change', 
  args=[A('pk')],
  accessor=A('__str__')  # or whatever attribute of your instance you want to display
)
```

Comment: I get `NameError: name 'A' is not defined`

Comment: `A` is a utility shortcut for the `Accessor` class from `django_tables2.utils`. Just import it.

Comment: I don't get any errors, but the edit column is just dashes

Comment: Well, you can use the `accessor` param to set whatever field/property/method of your model you wnat to display. Just as with any other column.

Comment: Now I'm getting an error with the lookup `Reverse for 'view_booking_Booking_change' with arguments '(44,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`

Comment: What is the name of your app and your model? Both should be lowercased in the view name!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141797/discussion-between-schwobaseggl-and-matt).